# How to get printf warnings in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, warnings, printf

When providing the wrong number of arguments to printf():

```
printf("%s", "foo", "bar");
```

or when by providing arguments of the wrong type:

```
printf("%d", "foo");
```

gcc is able to warn about these mistakes:

```
$ gcc -Wformat printf_too_many_arguments.c
printf_warnings.c: In function `main':
printf_warnings.c:5: warning: too many arguments for format
printf_warnings.c:5: warning: too many arguments for format

$ gcc -Wformat printf_argument_of_wrong_type.c
printf_warnings.c: In function `main':
printf_warnings.c:5: warning: format `%d' expects type `int', but argument 2 has type `char *'
printf_warnings.c:5: warning: format `%d' expects type `int', but argument 2 has type `char *'
```

How to get such warnings with Visual Studio 2005?

-- dave

Comment: The gcc compiler has special code in it that "knows" about the printf function and the format string. as far as I'm aware the MS compiler does not have this.

Answer (score 1):

I use cppcheck (http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) when working with Visual Studio 2005 which detects mismatches between the number of parameters provided to printf/wprintf and the number of parameters required.

Unfortunately it doesn't check the types match, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MSVC/Visual Studio does not support this.

See also [__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) for MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354784/attribute-formatprintf-1-2-for-msvc)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The lack of such warnings from Visual Studio is really bad.

Comment: Visual Studio has supported this for almost 10 years (including in VS2005): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402(v=vs.80).aspx, just pass the /analyze flag.

Answer (score 0):

You will need additional software to do this.  Take a look at PC-Lint (http://www.gimpel.com/).  It can find these kinds of errors (and much more [potential] errors as well).