# Equivalent of gcc's __attribute__ format in visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, printf

I had written a custom logging function which accepts a `printf` like format strings and gcc provides `__attribute__ (format)` for format string checks, is there a equivalent option in Visual C++ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) for MSVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354784/attribute-formatprintf-1-2-for-msvc)

Comment: yes, duplicate of the above question, good if someone can close this question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_attribute\_\_((format(printf, 1, 2))) for MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354784/attribute-formatprintf-1-2-for-msvc)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not, but you might use some variant of GCC (MinGW?) on your system.

Or you could even install a Linux system on your machine...