# How to cause SAL compiler warnings in my own code using Visual C++ without running static code analysis

Tags: c++, visual-c++, microsoft-sal

If I create a new console project in VS 2019 and add my own annotated implementation of `printf` and call both real `printf` and my version:

```
    // SALTest.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
    //

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdarg>

    int my_printf(_In_z_ _Printf_format_string_ char const* const format, ...)
    {
        va_list arglist;
        va_start(arglist, format);
        int result = _vfprintf_l(stdout, format, nullptr, arglist);
        va_end(arglist);
        return result;
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello World!\n");

        printf("printf good: %s\n", "narrow string");
        printf("printf bad: %s\n", L"wide string");
        my_printf("my_printf good: %s\n", "narrow string");
        my_printf("my_printf bad: %s\n", L"wide string");
    }
```

When I compile the file I see a compiler warning for the misuse of `printf` but not for the misuse of `my_printf`:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SALTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>SALTest.cpp
1>C:\Code\SALTest\SALTest.cpp(21,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'const wchar_t *'
```

Now it is true that I can "Run Code Analysis on File (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F7)" and that will give me code analysis warnings for both printf and my_printf in addition to the original compiler warning for printf:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SALTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>SALTest.cpp
1>C:\Code\SALTest\SALTest.cpp(21,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'const wchar_t *'
...
C:\Code\SALTest\SALTest.cpp(21): warning C6303: Format string mismatch:  wide character string passed as _Param_(2) when character string is required in call to 'printf' Actual type: 'const wchar_t [12]'.
C:\Code\SALTest\SALTest.cpp(23): warning C6303: Format string mismatch:  wide character string passed as _Param_(2) when character string is required in call to 'my_printf' Actual type: 'const wchar_t [12]'.
```

But my question is this: is it possible to get the same compiler warning for `my_printf` that I get for `printf` without resorting to running a code-analysis?
Turning on code-analysis for the huge project I'm on is not an option.

Comment: SAL annotations have no effect on the compiler, they are just empty macros. They only affect analysis tools

Comment: And yet somehow for printf they do have an effect.

Comment: No, they don't, actually. The compiler just has built-in knowledge of `printf` specifically (and other similar standard functions) and can thus validate its input at compile-time, that's all. That is a compiler extension. For instance, gcc offers a similar feature via `__attribute__((format(...)))` on function declarations, but MSVC does not support that feature on user-defined functions, only SAL annotations.

Comment: That is a shame.
I found another answer that confirms again what you said: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354784/attribute-formatprintf-1-2-for-msvc

Comment: @kaylum this question applies equally to C and C++ even tho the example code is C++ so I don't see the need to remove the C tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAL annotations have *no effect whatsoever* during the compiling stage, as they are implemented as empty preprocessor macros. They only have an effect on static analysis tools.

In the case of `printf()` (and other similar standard functions, like `scanf()`), modern compilers have built-in knowledge of the requirements of their parameters, and can thus validate user-provided parameter values at compile-time. But that a compiler extension, not defined by the C/C++ standards.

For instance, gcc and clang offer compile-time validation of a `printf`-style user function by decorating it with `__attribute__((format(...)))`, but [MSVC does not support that feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354784/) at this time, it only supports SAL annotations.